# syntax coloring does not work for flex file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm using nord theme, it works normally with other kind of files but not flex file
I have `syntax on` and `filetype on`
I tried switching colorthing from gruvbox to nord but it still behaving the same.
this is my vimrc file

```
set guifont=Fira\ Code\ 18
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv

" line number
set number

syntax on

filetype on                  " required

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
syntax oncall vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required


call plug#begin(has('nvim') ? stdpath('data') . '/plugged' : '~/.vim/plugged')

    " Any valid git URL is allowed
    Plug 'https://github.com/junegunn/vim-github-dashboard.git'

    " Using a non-default branch
    Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator', { 'branch': 'stable' }

    " Using a tagged release; wildcard allowed (requires git 1.9.2 or above)
    Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }

    Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
    Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

    Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'

    Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'

    "Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
call plug#end()
"let g:gruvbox_gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'soft'
"colorscheme gruvbox
"set background=dark

colorscheme nord

" custom key bindings
vmap <C-c> "+yi
vmap <C-x> "+c
vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+

" set compatibility to vim only
set nocompatibible

" status bar
set laststatus=2

"auto wrap text that extents beyond the sreen length
set wrap

" Encoding
set encoding=utf-8

filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab

set smartindent

" Auto save
let g:auto_save = 1
autocmd TextChanged, TextChangedI <buffer> silent write 
autocmd BufRead, BufNewFile * start 

" Airline
let g:airline_theme = 'base16_adwaita'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

set tags+=./tags;,tags

let g:zettelkasten = "/home/danhpc/opt/note_linked/"

" Make Ctrlp use ripgrep
if executable('rg')
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'rg %s --files --color=never --glob ""'
    let g:ctrlp_user_caching = 0
endif

" Make :grep use ripgrep
if executable('rg')
    set grepprg=rg\ --color=never\ --vimgrep
endif

" My own version, only searches markdown as well using ripgrep
" Thus depends on grepprg being set to rg
command! -nargs=1 Ngrep grep "<args>" -g "*.md" $NOTES_DIR
nnoremap <leader>nn :Ngrep<space>

command! Vlist botright vertical copen | vertical resize 50
nnoremap <leader>v :Vlist<CR>

" Generate ctags
nnoremap <leader>tt :silent !ctags -R . <CR>:redraw!<CR>

" Go to tag file
nnoremap <leader>nt :e $NOTES_DIR/tags<CR>:cd $NOTES_DIR<CR>

" Go to the note dir
nnoremap <leader>nd :ex $NOTES_DIR<CR>:cd $NOTES_DIR<CR>

" Change directory to directory of current file
nnoremap <leader>cd :cd %:h<CR>

" Binding for searching tags ("search tag")
nnoremap <leader>st :CtrlPTag<CR>

" 1) pre-fills all the stuff we don’t want to type, namely the timestamp and the extension (always markdown)
" 2) that prompts you for the name of your note
command! -nargs=1 NewZettel :execute ":e" zettelkasten . strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") . "-<args>.md"

nnoremap <leader>nz :NewZettel 

" CtrlP function for inserting a markdown link with Ctrl-X
function! CtrlPOpenFunc(action, line)
   if a:action =~ '^h$'    
      " Get the filename
      let filename = fnameescape(fnamemodify(a:line, ':t'))
      let l:filename_wo_timestamp = fnameescape(fnamemodify(a:line, ':t:s/\(^\d\+-\)\?\(.*\)\..\{1,3\}/\2/'))
      let l:filename_wo_timestamp = substitute(l:filename_wo_timestamp, "_", " ", "g")

      " Close CtrlP
      call ctrlp#exit()
      call ctrlp#mrufiles#add(filename)

      " Insert the markdown link to the file in the current buffer
      let mdlink = "[".filename_wo_timestamp."]( ".filename." )"
      put=mdlink
  else    
      " Use CtrlP's default file opening function
      call call('ctrlp#acceptfile', [a:action, a:line])
   endif
endfunction

let g:ctrlp_open_func = { 
         \ 'files': 'CtrlPOpenFunc',
         \ 'mru files': 'CtrlPOpenFunc' 
         \ }
```

Edit 1:
a part of my flex file

```
%x NESTED_COMMENT INLINE_COMMENT
int nested_level = 0;

%}

DARROW  =>

%%

// Nested comment

<INITIAL,NESTED_COMMENT>"(*"    {BEGIN NESTED_COMMENT;
                    ++nested_level;}
<NESTED_COMMENT>"*"+)   {if(nested_level) --nested_level;
            else BEGIN INITIAL;}
<NESTED_COMMENT>[^*)\n]+    { }
<NESTED_COMMENT>"*"+    { }
<NESTED_COMMENT>\n  { }

// inline comment
<INITIAL>
```

Edit 2
a picture of uncolored flex file
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) In order to understand or reproduce your problem we would need an example of flex file (ideally small) that is not display correctly and a description of what you dislike (a screenshot would be helpful to understand what you dislike).

Comment: You needn't include your whole `vimrc`. Since you did, may I say that it looks just a little bit cluttered? Two plugin managers being used, the same options being set multiple times etc.

Comment: Two plugin managers? Also, Vim doesn't appear to support syntax highlighting for "flex files". What are those, by the way? Are they related to https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/flex_1.html? Is the syntax close to lex, which is supported.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thank you for replying, I just added some edits please take a look.

Comment: @Friedrich haha, thank you for your honesty, I just got into Vim (I really enjoy it so far). First I just use `Plug` then I need `Vurdle` to isntall `YCM`. If you have any tips to make my `vimrc` more concise, I would really appreciate.

Comment: @romainl thank you for replying, yes, it is related to the one in your link. I just added some edits please have a look.

Comment: You can install any plugin with any plugin manager. To install YCM with vim-plug, use something like `Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe', {'do': './install.py <your options>'}`

Comment: @Friedrich oh, thank you sir. for letting me know.

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) would help you find a minimal reproduction for your problem. This can make answering the question a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Vim doesn't know anything about "flex": it doesn't detect it and doesn't provide specific syntax highlighting for it.

As a quick workaround, you can set the syntax to `lex` for flex files, which *is* supported. You can do it manually:

```
:set syntax=lex
```

or tell Vim to do it automatically for you:

```
" in ftdetect/flex.vim
" adjust the file pattern to taste
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.flex setfiletype lex
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.l` file extension, which is automatically recognized by Vim as `lex`:

[image: lex]

But I don't know if it will cover everything as there certainly are differences between flex and lex.

FWIW, there is [a plugin](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-syntax-extra/tree/master) that appears to provide updated syntax highlighting for lex/flex. You should probably give it a try.

Comment: this works for me nicely, thank you for your time.